# ngrx effect - combining two API

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have the below effect to update a part of an object using the `update` api, then i get the whole object by `findById` api, so i used `forkJoin` to combine those two api, but i want the `findById` api to be executed after 1 second from the `update` api, so i used  `delay(1000)`, but it's not working

```
@Effect()
updateGeographicScope$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<conventionsActions.PatchGeographicScope>(conventionsActions.ConventionActionTypes.PATCH_GEOGRAPHIC_SCOPE),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap(geographicScope => forkJoin(this.apiConvention.update(geographicScope),
        this.apiConvention.findById (geographicScope.externalId).pipe(delay(1000))).pipe(
            map(([first, convention]) => new conventionsActions.PatchSuccess({
                id: convention.externalId,
                changes: convention
            })),
            catchError(err => {
                console.error(err.message);
                return of(new conventionsActions.Failure({ concern: 'PATCH', error: err }));
            })
        ))
);
```

Comment: The `delay` operator only delay the result, not the request. You can replace `this.apiConvention.findById (geographicScope.externalId).pipe(delay(1000))` with `timer(1000).switchMapTo(this.apiConvention.findById (geographicScope.externalId))`. However, why 1s? it's OK even if the first request take 5s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `concat` and `timer` for that. With `concat` it the first stream to complete before starting the next one. So it makes update, then waits 1 second, then makes findById.

```js
@Effect()
updateGeographicScope$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<conventionsActions.PatchGeographicScope>(conventionsActions.ConventionActionTypes.PATCH_GEOGRAPHIC_SCOPE),
    map(action => action.payload),
    mergeMap(geographicScope => concat(
      this.apiConvention.update(geographicScope).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY)), // makes a request
      timer(1000).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY)), // waits 1 sec
      this.apiConvention.findById(geographicScope.externalId), // makes a request
    )),
    map(convention => new conventionsActions.PatchSuccess({
      id: convention.externalId,
      changes: convention
    })),
    catchError(err => {
      console.error(err.message);
      return of(new conventionsActions.Failure({ concern: 'PATCH', error: err }));
    }),
    repeat(), // make active after a failure
  )),
);
```

Comment: thnx for your answer, but i want to know what does `switchMapTo(EMPTY)` and `repeat()` do ?

Comment: `switchMapTo(EMPTY)` suppress all emits so they won't appear in `map`. `repeat` resubscribes in case of `catchError`, without it after a caught error the effect is completed and next emits of the action won't trigger it.